# Is it possible to have a Product Video from Vimeo instead of Youtube in BigCommerce?

Tags: themes, bigcommerce

When trying to create a product video

```
POST /stores/h79347hr0f/v3/catalog/products/132/videos HTTP/1.1
{
  "type": "vimeo",
  "video_id": "79880285"
}
```

I get the response

```
{
"status": 409,
"title": "Video with video_id 79880285 was not found on host site",
"type": "https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api#api-status-codes"
}
```

Is it possible to add another video provider, or turn of checking for videos on the host site? (presumably this is hard-coded to youtube)

I realize as a theme author, you'd have to update `templates\components\products\videos.html` and `assets\js\theme\product\video-gallery.js` to handle other video types

Answer (score 1):

YouTube is the only supported provider at this time.

<s>If you wanted to add a Vimeo embed, you could potentially modify your template to have Vimeo embed code instead and see if this ID still works.</s> Apparently this does not work.

Alternatively, you might consider storefront the Vimeo ID as a Product Custom Field and retrieving it into your own vimeo embed with conditional logic in the template.

Comment: the ids in youtube are different (alphanumeric) than the ids in vimeo (numeric)

Comment: I cannot mark this as correct, because the bit about the ID 'working' is misleading. It will still fail in the API call.

Comment: Edited for clarity. Also apparently my original response was truncated as well :)